# Does not find ValueMember after adding from another ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, listbox, selectedvalue

Have two `ListBox`. Double-click on the `lbSubject` element, adds this element to the second `lbSelectedSubject`. Provided that this element is not already in `lbSelectedSubject`. The check for the presence of elements goes through the `List<int>` to which `ValueMember` is added.

```
List<int> selectedValueSubject;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedValueSubject = new List<int>();
    lbSelectedSubject.DisplayMember = "Title";
    lbSelectedSubject.ValueMember = "Id";

    lbSubject.DataSource = bindingSubjectDefault;
    lbSubject.DisplayMember = "Title";
    lbSubject.ValueMember = "Id";
}

private void LbSubject_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = lbSubject.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        int id = (int)lbSubject.SelectedValue;
        if (IsNotConstrain(id, selectedValueSubject.ToArray()))
        {
            selectedValueSubject.Add(id);
            lbSelectedSubject.Items.Add(lbSubject.Items[index]);
        }
    }
}

private void LbSelectedSubject_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = lbSelectedSubject.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        selectedValueSubject.Remove((int)lbSelectedSubject.SelectedValue);
        lbSelectedSubject.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}

private bool IsNotConstrain(int id, int[] keys)
{
    bool result = true;
    foreach(int key in keys)
    {
        if (key == id)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The addition is correct. In the sense that the person creates and displays the `Title`. The problem is the reverse process. Remove from `lbSelectedSubject`. A string in `LbSelectedSubject_MouseDoubleClick` throws an exception:

```
lbSelectedSubject.SelectedValue
```

> System.NullReferenceException: "object Reference not pointing to object instance."
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

This `lbSelectedSubject.Items` contains the correct item and settings for `Display` and `Value`. `SelectedItem` also normally, not null.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

The same item in the list `lbSubject` contains the correct value `Value`, not `null`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Why after adding in the `lbSelectedSubject` through the line

```
lbSelectedSubject.Items.Add(lbSubject.Items[index]);
```

It turns out that SelectedValue does not work? Under other equal conditions `lbSubject`.

**UPDATE** It is not duplicate.

Comment: You have not set any kind of DataSource on the lbselectedSubject list. So no SelectedValue is available there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I don't know if this case is documented in that duplicate

Comment: @Steve how to fix? I do not understand how implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the SelectedValue property if the ListBox has no DataSource.
A simple workaround is to provide the second listbox with an empty datasource of the same type you have set for the first one.

So suppose to have your first ListBox binded to a class of this type

```
public class TitleData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}
```

Now when you build the first listbox DataSource you build as well the second DataSource with

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedValueSubject = new List<int>();
    bsSelected.DataSource = new List<TitleData>();

    lbSelectedSubject.DisplayMember = "Title";
    lbSelectedSubject.ValueMember = "Id";
    lbSelectedSubject.DataSource = bsSelected; // <= this is a BindingSource at the class level
    .....

}
```

Finally in the MouseDoubleClick event you can reference your data with SelectedItem and SelectedValue

```
private void LbSelectedSubject_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = lbSelectedSubject.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        // Always do this before removing the element from the BindingSource
        selectedValueSubject.Remove((int)lbSelectedSubject.SelectedValue);

        bsSelected.Remove(lbSelectedSubject.SelectedItem);
        // lbSelectedSubject.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

Also, a minor problem. Never set the DisplayMember and ValueMember after setting the Datasource property. Doing in that order will cause the Binding to happen two times, once when you set the Datasource and another one when you set the ValueMember.

Comment: `Never set the DisplayMember and ValueMember after setting the Datasource property`. I would do so. But I have problem. When I try to do DataSource through BindingSource for ListBox is OK. But when I do it for ComboBox and CheckedListBox are not OK. As soon as I reversed the assignment of the DataSource and DisplayMember - works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sorry but I cannot speculate on that problem. Perhaps a new question will help you more. However, are you now able to remove the selected object from the second list?

Comment: Your answer helped me. Now I can remove an item so as and wanted to. I needed change an `anonymous type` to `MyItem` class for EF Core (`select new MyItem{}`). Okay, I will create new question.

Comment: Glad to be of help. See you again on SO

Comment: maybe you know [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726783/display-and-value-members-after-and-before-assignment-datasource)

Comment: or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751453/a-value-didnt-updated-entity-framework)